# ¿Cómo crear un botón tipo guardar cómo en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo un programa tipo GUI en python que genera un txt, lo único que me gustaría es que al darle click a un botón me abra el explorador de archivos y yo elija la ubicación deseada para guardar el txt generado.

Quizá es muy básico pero agradecería mucho algún ejemplo. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lanzar el diálogo y preguntar por el nombre del archivo, puedes valerte de la función `asksaveasfile()` del paquete `filedialog` de `tkinter`, por ejemplo:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
if (f): 
    f.write("hola mundo, soy un archivo")
    f.close()
```

Si el diálogo se cierra con el botón de cancelar, `f` será `None`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! prácticamente bastó con esta linea "f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")" Te lo agradezco